# How to pass integer list to Web API method from jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, jqgrid, asp.net-web-api2

Browser calls ASP.NET MVC4 application Web API method by passing list of jqgrid selected rows using

```
var selected = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
$.ajax( "/admin/api/Limiit",
      {
                  data: { selected: JSON.stringify(selected), 
                          key2: "somevalue"
                         },
                  type: 'POST',
      });
```

This generates POST request whose body contains integer list as selected parameter value:

```
POST /admin/api/Limiit HTTP/1.1

selected:["1","4","5","13","14"]
```

Web API Controller contains method to process this:

```
public class LimiitController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(int[] selected, string somevalue)
    {
        if (selected == null || selected.Length == 0)
            throw new ApplicationException("No rows selected");
    }
}
```

If code runs, selected parameter controller is always empty.
I tried also

```
    public void Post(string[] selected)
```

but problem persists.

How to pass integer list to Web API method from jqgrid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

**Javascript Code:**

```
    var selected = ["1", "4", "5", "13", "14"];
    var arr = [];
    var resultArr = [];     

    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++)
    {
        arr.push({ sID: selected[i] })
    }

    resultArr.push({ Selected: arr });

    $.ajax( "/admin/api/Limiit",
    {
        data: resultArr[0],
        type: 'POST',
    });
```

**Controller code:**

```
namespace Sample.Controllers
{
    public class Selected
    {
        public object sId { get; set;}
    }
    public class SelectedList
    {
        public List<Selected> Selected { get; set; }
    }

    public class LimiitController : ApiController
    {
        public void Post(SelectedList selected)
        {
            if (selected == null || selected.Length == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException("No rows selected");
        }
    }
}
```

**Request:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: data in answer user hard-coded values. How to create such data from dynamic data (jqgrid selected row ids as shown in answer)

Comment: @Andrus: I have updated the Javascript Code part. verify it and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to serialize array of strings to comma separated strings: `selected.join(",")`, send the string and to use `Split` to convert the string back to array of strings. It's probably not so elegant, but it works perfectly in every environment.

Comment: If string contains comma, `selected.join(",")` produces invalid list. How to create comma separated string if strings can contain comma ?

Comment: @Andrus: The example `selected.join(",")` corresponds the data which you posted. You should know at least one Unicode character which can't be in the id. It could be space for example which is not allowed to be used in id. For example if the char with Unicode code `1` (`\u0001`) is not used in ids then `var str = t.join("\u0001");` will get you the string which can be send and `var ar = str.split("\u0001");` will convert the string to the array back (in JavaScript, in C# - `String.Split` of cause).

Answer (score 0):

Make the AJAX call like this

```
var selected = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
$.ajax( "/admin/api/Limiit",
{
    data: { JSON.stringify(selected) },
    type: 'POST',
});
```

so that the HTTP request is like this.

```
POST /admin/api/Limiit HTTP/1.1

["1","4","5","13","14"]
```

That should bind correctly to your action method `public void Post(string[] selected)`. `[FromBody]` is optional here, since `string[]` is complex type and by default, body is used.

UPDATE

Make the AJAX call like this

```
var selected = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
var postData = { selected: selected, key2: "somevalue"};
$.ajax( "/admin/api/Limiit",
{
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    type: 'POST',
});
```

This way, your request body will be like this.

`{ "selected" : ["1", "4", "5"], "key2" : "somevalue" }`

Then, have the action method like this.

```
public void Post(MyDto dto)
{
    // Use dto.Selected and dto.Key2 here
}

public class MyDto
{
    public string[] Selected { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that post buffer contains only single key. How to use it if there are multiple keys is post buffer ? I updaded question